# Do I need "had" in the following example?

Tags: past-tense

> She told me they found him hanging in his parent's house. He **(had)** used
>   his climbing rope, tied so that he could pull himself up from the
>   floor.

Do I need that **had**? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's appropriate to use *had used* in this sentence, because the Past Perfect expresses the idea that something occurred before another action in the past.
Action in the second part of this sentence was before that they found him hanging.

Comment: Yes but it is obvious that he chose his climbing rope before he tied himself and hung  so I think past perfect would not be necessary in that case . Or if you employ that tense it is to emphasize the connection between the climbing rope and how he used" he used it because he wanted to committ suicide